# Google Play Store Facebook Share

Tags: facebook, google-play

I tried sharing a link to my app on Facebook and the title and description show up fine, but for some reason there is not an image in the share like a normal link would show (I would expect at least the Play logo, if not my app's logo).

Is there a way for me to specify what logo to show when sharing my Play app on Facebook?