# How to change preview image of Play Store app when sharing on Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, google-play

I've changed my application's icon and Feature Graphic,Promo Graphic on google play a week ago but
when I copy the link of my appliaction and share it on facebook, the preview on facebook show the older of my application's icon.So, how can I make it to show the lastest Icon when sharing it?
I know my question is similar to bellow questions:

1. [How to change preview of Play Store app when sharing on Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228658/how-to-change-preview-of-play-store-app-when-sharing-on-facebook).
2. [Google Play Store Facebook Share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957725/google-play-store-facebook-share)

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the icon is changed in the manifest file

Comment: there is a two icon app icon and a rounded icon if you changed and update the apk in playstore and changed the playstore app icon then the playstore have few time to change the icon.